# Delay pop-up for 10 seconds, only pop up once

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox

Hi I'm using the fancybox inline pop-up to to alert a view to a promotion. The code I'm using for this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#various1").fancybox();
});
```

How would I modify this so it automaticly popped up after, say, 20 seconds? But once it's been closed it schouldn't pop up again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, none of the solutions posted previously work in real life, why?
because the line:

```
$("#various1").fancybox();
```

doesn't trigger fancybox, it just binds fancybox to the selector #various1, but it still needs a click to trigger the modal/lightbox (not a popup). BTW, Gearóid's solution has syntax errors anyway. The only real value is that they suggest the use of the [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) (old site).

**EDIT**: (March 07, 2012) The jQuery cookie plugin home page [moved here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Steps for a working solution:

A) Load the jQuery cookie plugin (as suggested) after jQuery and fancybox js files

B) Then use this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout( function() {$('#various1').trigger('click'); },20000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 7 });
    $('#various1').fancybox();
});
</script>
```

C) you still need to have somewhere in your html code (maybe hidden)

> ```
> <a id="various1" href="path/target"></a>
> ```

or for inline content

```
<a id="various1" href="#target"></a>
<div style="display: none;">
 <div id="target">message to display in fancybox</div>
</div>
```

Also, if you use inline content and fancybox v1.3.x, check for an existing bug and workaround [here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/fab7b6d81a173b33/)

PS. fancybox is not a popup but a modal/lightbox jQuery plugin, which is a non-intrusive solution like jGrowl from a UI point of view.

Comment: THANKS JFK !! only problem the jquery cookie plugin link you provided is dead do you know where i could find the information on that ? again thanks for al the help

Comment: I know I'm way late, just wanted to say this answer is perfect!

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#various1").fancybox();
  }, 20000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Use Timeout function. The solution for your query is below
$(document).ready(function () {
setTimeout(function() {
$('your modal id').modal('show')  }, 10000); //displays modal after 10 seconds
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setTimeout` function in javascript:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // first wait 20 seconds before this popups
    $("#various1").fancybox();

    setTimeout(function() {
        //.. what to do after 10 seconds
    }, 10000);

}, 20000);
```

I hope this is what you want? Your title and explanation is confusing

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `delay` function for this:

```
$("#various1").delay(20000).fancybox();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use setTimeout to delay the popup like so:

```
setTimeout("showPopup()",20000);

function showPopup() {
    if (null != $.cookie("offer_closed"))
         $("#various1").fancybox();});
}
```

The use the [jQuery cookie library](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) to set a cookie (call it something like "offer_closed") to true when the user clicks close. This then signals that the popup was already displayed.

PS. From a UI point of view, you should try to avoid solutions using popups. Users hate them. [Try a more elegant solution like jGrowl.](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html)

Comment: you can set it to true after displaying the box.
example here: http://radarvicieux.com/ after 15s or so

Comment: You never feed a string to `setTimeout`. Just pass the function name (or the function itself).

Comment: @Tomalak Actually you *have* to feed a string to it. Passing the function name causes a timeout but the function won't be invoked.

Comment: this is because you must define the function before you use it. Try placing the `setTimeout()` call below the function definition.

Comment: @Tomalak, this is an interesting one. If you wish to specify the function with parentheses then you need to pass it as a string. If you call it as a function with parentheses (as you would normal js functions) then the function gets invoked immediately thus rendering the timeout useless. Tested on FF 8.0.1

Comment: @Gearóid I did never say that you should *call* the function. I said you should *pass* it: `setTimeout(showPopup, 20000);`.

Answer (score 0):

See the below code example, popup will open after 5 seconds on page load with a message "Welcome to site name" -

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        openFancybox();
        $('#various1').fancybox();
    });
    function openFancybox() {
        setTimeout( function() {$('#various1').trigger('click'); },5000);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a id="various1" href="#target"></a>
<div style="display: none;">
 <div id="target">welcome to shoesdekho.com</div>
</div>
</body>
```