# Trouble with a realy simple jquery script

Tags: jquery, fancybox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delay pop-up for 10 seconds, only pop up once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298886/delay-pop-up-for-10-seconds-only-pop-up-once)

Im having trouble getting this script to run, its somthing realy simple i know.. i still have allot to learn about js. thanks in advance !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(20000);
        $function showPopup() {
            $("#various1").fancybox();});
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$function
```

should probably be

```
function
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code has a few issues. First is your use of setTimeout() and the other is some extra punctuation. I'm guessing you want something like:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout('$("#various1").fancybox()', 20000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is not valid.  Can you re-examine it?  Also the javascript setTimeout call is incorrect. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#various1").fancybox();
        }, 20000);
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra `)` and/or `}` in there somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Also you have too many });.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(20000);
function showPopup() {
$("#various1").fancybox();
}}
);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A we have to guess at what you are trying to achieve, I am guessing it is something like the below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#various1").fancybox();
        }, 20000);
    });
</script>
```

To clarify:

setTimeout is a method used to perform a function at a given interval. I am assuming you want to perform the $("#various1").fancybox() every 20000 milliseconds.

Comment: thanks for all the imput - what im trying to achive is after 20 seconds fire the fancybox but only fire it once ..

Comment: Actually I think Im getting confused with 'setInterval'. SetTimeout occurs once and once only, 'setInterval' reoccurs at the given number of miliseconds. Is the above code not working?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually duplicating your question with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8298886/1055987) but with a different title.

I already gave you a working solution on the previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305703/1055987)