# I would like to launch a Fancybox (e.g. Fancybox's version of a modal or light box) on page load

Tags: fancybox

I do not know where to plug in the script to be able to have a fancy box open on page load for an add. can anyone help if I send them my code?

Comment: Whats the problem? Have you tried it on document ready jquery event?

Comment: Why don't you post your code here?  =)

Answer (score 0):

If using fancybox v1.3.4, check http://fancybox.net/blog No. 6

If using fancybox v2.x, check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No. 11

If you want to launch fancybox only when the visitor goes to the page the first time, you could also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305703/1055987