# Set delay for lightbox popup using cookie script

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup

I've successfully managed to get jquery.cookie.js working on my lightbox popup using the code below which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420201/one-time-fancybox-popup-like-on-digg-com).

Now I would like to add a function in there to set a delay of a couple seconds before it fires, but I can't figure out where to alter the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if (jQuery.cookie('test_status') != '1') {
   jQuery('#myModal').reveal()
     jQuery('#myModal').trigger('click');
     jQuery.cookie('test_status', '1', { expires: 7}); }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    if (jQuery.cookie('test_status') != '1')
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            jQuery('#myModal').reveal()
            jQuery('#myModal').trigger('click');
            jQuery.cookie('test_status', '1', { expires: 7}); 
        }, 1000);// Delay in milliseconds
    }
});
```

Some formatting would make it easier to modify