# Fancybox one-time popup

Tags: fancybox

I used your suggestions on [Delay pop-up for 10 seconds, only pop up once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298886/delay-pop-up-for-10-seconds-only-pop-up-once/8305703), however it's not working. Do I need to do something like `<body onload='$("#various1").trigger("click");'>`
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so ... but, where is your code? ... got a link?