# fancybox display after time delay on session

Tags: jquery, cookies, fancybox

I'm trying to display a fancybox popup which should only popup after the user has been on the site for 1 minute 30 seconds, so i needs to record the session time (not display on every page load).
Then I need to add a checkbox to the popup for people to choose not to display the popup again, so adds a cookie.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#target").hide().delay(9000).show();
  })
</script>

    <p>This is a demo. </p>

    <ul>
        <li><a id="fancybox" href="#target">popup</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="target" style="width:620px;display: none; height:500px;overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y:scroll ">
        <p>Popup test</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm a total novice, I can add the delay. But don't know how to do it session based or add the cookie.

Comment: Adding some code to your question will get you more answers, it shows some research effort and not just "I want this, do it for me" question.

Comment: I've added where I'm at at the moment. Thanks again,

Comment: Find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8305703/1055987

Answer (score 0):

Simple timers can be created in JavaScript using the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) function (execute some once code after a specified period of time) or the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) function (execute some code repeatedly at the specified intervals)