# Fancybox pop-up and cookies not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, shopify

I have been working on a shopify site to install a form through fancybox, while using cookies to only show on the first visit.  I am having issues  getting fancybox to appear on load of the page, but if I take out the fancybox code the form loads inline on the page.  This makes me suspect that I am doing something wrong with calling fancybox.  Also, I don't think the cookies are working properly.  I don't see them through Firebug.

Here is the code that is at the bottom of my index.liquid

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document.ready(function() {
        if ($.cookie('rrp8')) {
         // it hasn't been 120 days yet
      } else {
          $.fancybox(
   '<div id="home-pop"><p style="text-align: left;">Sign up here for updates on new classes, future dates &amp; more</p><form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="oid" value="00DU0000000J1yb" /><input type=hidden name="oid" value="00DU0000000J1yb"><input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0149/4308/files/pop-up-thanks.png?76"><input type=hidden name="LeadSource" value="Training Store"><div><table><tbody><tr><td><label for="first_name">First Name:</label><br><input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" size="26" maxlength="40" />&nbsp;<br></td></tr><tr><td><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label><br><input id="last_name" type="text" name="first_name" size="26" maxlength="40" />&nbsp;<br></td></tr><tr><td><label for="email">Email:</label><br><input  id="sf_email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="26" type="text" /><br></td></tr><tr><td><label for="company">Company:</label><br><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="26" type="text" /><br></td></tr><tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr></tbody></table></div></form></div>',
             {
                 'autoDimensions'    : true,
                 'width'             : 570,
                 'height'            : 530,
                 'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                 'transitionOut'     : 'fade'
              }
          );
       }
   });
   // set cookie to expire in 120 days
   $.cookie('rrp8', 'true', { expires: 120});
   </script>
```

And here is the code in the theme.liquid

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {{ 'jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
    {{ 'jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
    {{ 'jquery.cookie.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
    {{ 'jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

I posted this on the shopify forums but i have not received a response yet.  I am hoping someone can help.

*UPDATE*
When I add the following "simplified" code to a plain html file, fancybox works.  When I add it to Shopify, nothing appears.  I assume my error is somewhere in shopify, just don't know where.
        
        
        
          
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
                $(function(){
                var myContent = 'Sign up here for updates on new classes, future dates & more

First Name:
 
Last Name:
 
Email:
Company:
';

```
    $.fancybox(myContent,
                 {
                     'autoDimensions'    : true,
                     'width'             : 570,
                     'height'            : 530,
                     'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                     'transitionOut'     : 'fade'
                  }
              );
    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I should note that I have tried the links in the theme.liquid as above and as full URLs without the liquid formatting.

Comment: Have you tried `true` without quotes? normally Boolean or integer values go without quotes, otherwise you have to validate the cookie value as a string `if ($.cookie('rrp8') == "true")`.

Comment: You could also check my answer of a year ago where I used variables instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/8305703/1055987

Comment: .... BTW, your fancybox code seems to be working fine. Check http://jsfiddle.net/Wp6LT/ (I just removed the shopify references to avoid cross-domain issues)

Comment: I just tried `true` without quotes, I actually tried your answer from a year ago yesterday, and I tried updating with the code from jsfiddle - nothing is working.

Comment: I finally have it working by using [http://jsfiddle.net/Wp6LT/](http://jsfiddle.net/Wp6LT/).  Any thoughts on how to set a cookie so that users only see it once every 120 days?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your issue of getting the cookie part to work,
I've modified your jsfiddle and it appears to be working fine.

All I did was make sure to include the jquery cookie plugin.

Perhaps your jquery.cookie javascript file isn't loading? have you checked firebug/chrome's inspector to make sure all resources are loading?

> ```
> <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.3/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
> ```

You can load it from a CDN as I have above, or download it from github: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js

## JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/Wp6LT/2/

run the fiddle once and the form shows, run it again and an alert will indicate the cookie was found.

## By the way...

You should probably update the jQuery version you're using. We're on 1.8 now but yours is way back on 1.4

Here's a CDN for 1.8:

> ```
> <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```