# Hide div after X number of visits (cookies)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am looking for a solution where a div is not showing anymore after X number of visits. I don't have a lot of experience with Javascript and since I'm in a bit of a hurry I was hoping if someone knew the solution out here since I can't find any online anywhere.

I found this thread that almost does what I'm looking for:
[JS cookie for displaying content after x-th pageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479439/js-cookie-for-displaying-content-after-x-th-pageview) but there they are showing a lightbox after a number of visits, I want to hide a div (class or id) after X number of visits.

They are using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create cookie
  var visited = $.cookie('visited'); // visited = 0
  if (visited >= 3) {
    // open fancybox on 4th visit or further on the same day
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.fancybox.open({});
    }, 3000);
  } else {
    visited++; // increase counter of visits
    // set new cookie value to match visits
    $.cookie('visited', visited, {
      expires: 1 // expires after one day
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery **[`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)** method like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var X = 4;
  var visited = $.cookie('visited');

  if (visited >= X) {
    $('your_div_selector').hide(); //<--- HERE IS THE LINE YOU NEED
  } else {
    visited++;

    $.cookie('visited', visited, {
      expires: 1
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: You're weclome, Glad I could help.