# Display a modal after x pages views with JS Cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

I'm trying to display a Bootstrap modal avec 3 pages viewed on my website, and find an actualized solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479439/js-cookie-for-displaying-content-after-x-th-pageview) question, with the JS-Cookie plugin.

I tried this code but it's not working :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // create cookie
    var visited = Cookies('visited'); // visited = 0
    if (visited >= 3) {
        // open fancybox after 3 secs on 4th visit or further on the same day
        $('#my_modal').modal('show');
    } else {
        visited++; // increase counter of visits
        // set new cookie value to match visits
        Cookies('visited', visited, {
            expires: 1 // expires after one day
        });
        return false;
    }
}); // ready
```

What the code above should do : promp the modal after 4 page reload, [like here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxOn4pageView_24jan12.html)
What is not working : I reaload the page but the modal not appears

Here is my cookie state (on chrome) :
[Image on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl8jz.png)

This is a sample of code that actually works for to display a modal on the first visit of the website :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (Cookies('pop_welcome') == null) {
         $('#my_modal').modal('show');
     Cookies('pop_welcome', '31', { expires: 31 });
  }
 });
```

** -- Solution -- **

You can find the solution [into @greedchikara code snip](https://codepen.io/greedchikara/pen/jRPXXP)

The code :

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

var visited = readCookie('tester') || 1;

if (visited > 2) {
  $('#my_modal').modal('show');
} else {
  visited++;
  createCookie('tester', visited, 1);
}
```

---

Can you please help me ?
Thanks

[Here is the code of the JS cookie plugin.](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Comment: Check the console for errors. Note that `Cookies` isn't a standard method, so unless you've added that yourself it will be causing an error

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This code does not prompt any error on my chrome console... I edited my question with a working code snip with Cookies method

Comment: check whether ```$('#my_modal').modal('show');``` is opening the modal from console

Comment: So what does `Cookies('visited')` return? You show it returns `0` in comments. Do some logging of that to console and see what's happening

Comment: @greedchikara the cookie is not opening the modal. The cookie is present but not doing anything :'(

Comment: @charlietfl the cookie "visited" returns 'NaN'. But with my working code, it returns '31'... I don't understand

Comment: So maybe it won't accept numbers, only string? cookies themselves are all strings Any docs link for `Cookies` method?

Comment: @charlietfl Many thanks for your perseverance. I added the code of the js file of the plugin. The plugin is here : https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie.

Comment: If having problems with that cookie approach... using localStorage is very simple and doesn't require loading an extra script like Cookies

Comment: @charlietfl If you have a solution without JSCookie I take it. It's the only solution I found to use Cookie on JS (I'm a rails backend dev with no skills on JS)

Comment: `var visited = +(localStorage.getItem('visited') ||0);` ....then to set it `localStorage.setItem('visited', visited)`. Requires no script dependency, is api built into browser

Comment: @charlietfl localstorage call is synchronous, I would avoid it. Instead you can use three simple function for cookie

Comment: @charlietfl I added `var visited = +(localStorage.getItem('visited') ||0);` and it's render "1" (was "NaN") but the modal don't appears... I'm not sure to know how to "set" `localStorage...`

Comment: @greedchikara why is being synchronous a problem? I use it all the time. Cookies add extra overhead to every request to server

Comment: Since the current cookie data is not required by the server, therefore it makes sense to store in localstorage to your point @charlietfl For solving it with cookie checkout this  https://codepen.io/greedchikara/pen/jRPXXP?editors=1010

Comment: @greedchikara how can I use your code snip? Sorry but I don't understand...

Comment: create a js file, paste those three functions namely createCookie, readCookie, eraseCookie. In your case ```var visited = readCookie('visited') || 1; if (visited > 3) { .. } else { visited++; createCookie('visited', visited, 1); }```

Comment: @greedchikara I added the code on a edit of the answer, but it's non rendering anything...

Comment: Ok lets break it into pieces, 
*first check the content of the cookie using ```readCookie('cookietest')``` on chrome console, if it is updating then cookie is working fine
*second on chrome console run this ```$('#myModal').modal('show');```, if you modal is appearing then fine else something with the modal.

Comment: i have updated the link https://codepen.io/greedchikara/pen/jRPXXP with example try reloading for 3 times and it will give you alert after 3rd reload

Comment: @greedchikara thanks for your help. readCookie('cookietest') render : "Uncaught ReferenceError: readCookie is not defined". With the first method, I see the cookie in the cookie toggle near of the adress bar but with your last snip. In the other hand the command, `$('#myModal').modal('show');` prompt the modal.

Comment: Those 3 cookie functions needs to be loaded at top like you add jqueryjs first and then bootstrapjs

Comment: @greedchikara it's working with your snip ! Thank you so much for your time and the solution..! Please add it into an answer :) Thanks again!! Many thanks to charlieftl too.

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these simple three function to perform cookie tasks, no third party library needed.

```js
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create cookie
  var visited = $.cookie('visited'); // visited = 0
  if (visited >= 3) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#my_modal').modal('show'); //make sure model is already created with id my_model 
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    visited++; // increase counter of visits
    // set new cookie value to match visits
    $.cookie('visited', visited, {
      expires: 1 // expires after one day
    });
    return false;
  }
});


Make sure all dependent js are included.
```

jQuery plugin is here
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Answer with no explanation of what was changed and why is almost useless

Comment: I have tested it on my system, make sure you have added correct jquery cookie plugin.

Comment: I @NaruKeer, the JqueryCookie plugin is deprecated, and I use his replacer JSCookie

Comment: while first time page loaded , cookie is returning NaN value to handle this add   if(typeof visited=='undefined'){  var visited=0;}
 just before the if condition, as you are doing visited++  so this variable should have integer value.