# I need a "do not show again" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am a huge amateur when it comes to javascript and jquery, I can barely read it.

I tried the solution posted at [FancyBox - "Don't show this message again" button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841698/fancybox-dont-show-this-message-again-button), however it doesn't seem to work for me when I test it.

I need a button that hides a certain element (by ID) and creates a cookie that makes sure that person doesn't see that message again.

I have this text:

```
<p id="guidelinestext" class="guidelinestext">Please make sure to read our <a target="_blank" href="http://www.uqreview.com/review-guidelines/">Review Guidelines</a> before posting a review.</p>
```

and I need a button that says "Don't show this again"

Really sorry if this is a stupid question. Hopefully it is easy to answer. Thank you.

Comment: Its not how it works, if you are a huge amateur, you should at least try something your self to learn and then ask, if you dont understand... waht you asking is, somebody to do the work for you.

Comment: Show your code, please. That question seems to cover things well, as does this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833775/add-cookie-to-fancy-box-popup

Comment: If you *can barely read...* JavaScript may I suggest you try learning how to read it. This will probably help when writing JavaScript. Maybe a try a book....

Answer (score 9):

just use html5 localStorage

```
<button id="forgetMe">Don't show this again</button>

<script>
    if(localStorage.getItem("DontShow")) {
        $("#forgetMe").hide();
    }
    $(document).on("click", "#forgetMe", function() {
        localStorage.setItem("DontShow", "true");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It simple using a JQuery plugin - [JQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/):

```
$('#button-id').on('click', function() {
   $.cookie("buttonClicked", "YES"); 
});
```

Somewhere in your code, loading main page for instance:

```
var isVisited = $.cookie("buttonClicked"); 
if(isVisited === 'YES') {
   showButton();
} else {
   hideButton();
}

var showButton = function() {
  $('#button-id').show();   
} 

var hideButton = function() {
  $('#button-id').hide();   
}
```

Or whatever you have to do!

If in any case you have to remove the coockie, you can call:

```
$.removeCookie("buttonClicked");
```

## edit

as I can see from your webpage, you are doing..strange! I suggest to:

- create your file custom.js
- call custom.js after all jquery plugin

Your file custom.js will be:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
         /* insert here code above */   
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: is $.cookie a standard jquery function?

Comment: sorry I forget a link!

Comment: This isn't working for me.... I MUST be doing something very wrong. You can check it out at http://www.uqreview.com/courses/biol2001/

Comment: uhm.. in which file are you using coockie plugin?

Comment: I am linking to http://www.uqreview.com/cookies/jquery.cookie.js

but while searching for that link in my code, I found that the theme I am using is also calling on that file. Is it bad if it is put in the code twice?

Comment: I'm watching your test, follow edit instruction and tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

Create the button:

```
<button id="dontshow" onclick="dontshow();return false;">Don't show this again</button>
```

Get this plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

set the cookie on the button click:

```
function dontshow(){
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 30 }); // Set the cookie.
}
```

On startup, check if the cookie exists:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        $("#guidelinestext").hide();
    } else {
        $("#guidelinestext").show(); // cookie has no value, so show the text
    }
});
```

Comment: This isn't working. You can check my source code at http://uqreview.com/courses/biol2001/. I have all of this in there but it doesn't seem to work. I also have my header loading the jquery file and the jquery cookie file. Please help!

Comment: If you check it in Chrome and F12 you see there is an error. Try jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { instead of $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: I get an error when I click

Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
onclick

I also get this error


Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: I also tried your idea of changing it to jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

and I dont get the other error, but I still get the error:

Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (index):356
onclick

Comment: In your current code you need to change show() and hide(); Also, you need to set $("#guidelinestext").hide(); just after you set the cookie in the donshow()-method