# Jquery $.cookie isn't a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

So I'm using codeigniter as framework. I want to make my homepage to load a fancybox (prompt user to enter email address to subscribe with us). So I load the below code inside  tag

```
<?php echo link_tag("assets/css/main/jquery.fancybox.css"); ?>
<?php echo script_tag("assets/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"); ?>
<?php echo script_tag("assets/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"); ?>
<?php echo script_tag("assets/js/jquery.cookie.js"); ?>
```

And this is the link that is going to be loaded inside fancybox

```
<a id="autostart" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href='<?php echo base_url();?>subscribe'></a>
```

And I followed the step-by-step from [Delay pop-up for 10 seconds, only pop up once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298886/delay-pop-up-for-10-seconds-only-pop-up-once/8305703#8305703)

But it just won't work. Firebug says "$.cookie is not a function"
My files exist inside assets folder, nothing is missing.

When I do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

            $("#autostart").fancybox({
            'overlayShow':true,
            maxWidth    : 1064,
            maxHeight   : 2000,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '100%',
            height      : '100%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : true,
            openEffect  : 'elastic',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            showEarly  : true
        }).trigger('click'); 



});
```

the website will load the subscription page just fine. Why can't I use cookie plugin? I really only need to display the subscription page (where user enter his email) once a day...

Answer (score 0):

Seem like the browser cannot load your jQuery cookie file. You need to make sure that the path to your script is correct by checking in the network or console tab from firebug or chrome developer tools.

Another way is to use direct link to jQuery cookie script, so try to remove:

```
<?php echo script_tag("assets/js/jquery.cookie.js"); ?>
```

and use:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```