# jQuery cookie and fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2, jquery-cookie

I am trying to create a cookie using jQuery-cookie to store if a user has been to a page and if so not to display a fancybox modal. The cookie is to then be destroyed on browser close.

The code I have is:

**index.html**

```
<div class="nav-button"><a id="intro" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="intro"><img src="img/intro.png"></a></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#intro").trigger('click');
});
```

**main.js**

```
var elements = ['#top-menu', '#footer'];

function hideInterface() {
    $.each(elements, function(i) {
        $(elements[i]).hide();
    });
}

function showInterface() {
    $.each(elements, function(i) {
        $(elements[i]).show();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.nav-button a').click(function(e) {
        hideInterface();
    });

    $('#intro').fancybox({
      type: 'ajax',
      autoSize: false,
      width: '50%',
      height: '80%',
      minHeight: '650px',
      topRatio: 0.4,leftRatio: 0.5, 
      maxWidth: '990px',
      wrapCSS: 'black-skin',
      padding: 0,
      parent: '#app-container',
      scrolling: 'no',
      afterClose: function() {
          showInterface();
      }
    });
});
```

The cookie code I am trying to add is into the index.html which is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.cookie('myCookie')){
    return false;
  }else {
    $("#intro").trigger('click');
    $.cookie('myCookie', true);    
  } 
});
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: what is your problem exactly ? `The cookie is to then be destroyed on browser close.` i don't get it

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8305703/1055987?