# FancyBox isn't displaying once - using cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, fancybox

So I've tried to find an answer but can't seem to get this one right.
I've changed my code to model (pretty much exactly) after the answer in this question: 
[Delay pop-up for 10 seconds, only pop up once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298886/delay-pop-up-for-10-seconds-only-pop-up-once)

When I test locally, I can get it to work if I change the cookie value to a number(ex:1) instead of the string (ex: 'yes') but after putting the site online, the fancy box never shows up using either method. Tried clearing cookies and emptying cache.

Here's my code for the popup:

```
<!--This is for a one time popup-->
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!--Add fancybox CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<!-- Add jQuery cookie library -->
<script src="cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function openFancybox(){
    $('.fancybox').fancybox().trigger('click');
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
      return false;
    } 
    else {
      openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes' , { expires: 2 });
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    });
</script>
<!--End of popup code-->
```

In my html body I have:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" title="Next Generation City"></a>
```

and

```
<div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display:none;">
    <h3>About website.com </h3>
    <p>
     Here's my text for popup
    </p>
  </div>
```

I'm new to using cookies and fancy box, so I'm a little lost. Thanks so much for any help with this issue.

EDIT: also, I have a fancy box displaying correctly on another page of the site, so I'm fairly certain the issue is with the cookie part

Comment: if that works locally, check your paths when online

Comment: thanks so much! stupid mistake, didn't upload cookie javascript file, but checking the paths helped me find it