# Fancybox 2.1.4 - Loading content issues, BAD UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, fancybox

Hey :) I have a small loading issue.. There is a popup opening on a button click on my website, everything works fine, but there is also content inside the generated popup (by javascript) So it loads a while after the popup is already open and my "static" content is there. When the javascript content on the bottom of the popup gets loaded now, it will ofc resize the whole popup and everything looks a bit wonky..(it moves around, because the javascript content is a picture slider so to speak)

My code for loading the popup is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.fancybox.open([
        {
        type: 'inline',
        href : '#popupContent',                
    }
], {
    closeClick: false,
    autoResize: true,
    closeBtn: false,
    hideOnContentClick: true,
    hideOnOverlayClick: false,
    autoSize: true,
    padding : 0
  });
});

</script>
```

I thought about puttin a delay on the open for the popup so the javascrip slider has enough time.. but idk if that would work. Any ideas how to implement that into my code?

I hope you have any idea how i can fix this :) <3

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298886/delay-pop-up-for-10-seconds-only-pop-up-once

Comment: Maybe upgrade to v3? It already has touch functionality.