# Fancybox Modal with jquery cookie to open once on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, fancybox, jquery-cookie

I have a modal that opens in fancybox. I can fire this modal on page load by clicking the open modal button with jquery:

```
$("#download-brochure-button").fancybox().trigger('click');
```

I am trying to set a cookie so that this only opens once per session. I am looking in the chrome inspector under application tab and I cannot see any cookie being generated.  I am using [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to handle the cookie but I must be doing something wrong. Here is my js:

```
//Brochure Modal with cookie
$(document).ready(function(){
    var check_cookie = $.cookie('brochure_modal_cookie');
    if(check_cookie === null){
        $.cookie('brochure_modal_cookie', 'value', { expires: 7 });
        $("#download-brochure-button").fancybox().trigger('click');
   }
});
```

Currently no modal shows and no cookie can be seen.  Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you select `Cookies` sub-tab under `Application`  tab to verify? Also, try `console.log(check_cookie)` to see what you actually get!

Comment: console.log(check_cookie) gives me undefined, which I think is the same as null?  Also I tried to simple set a cookie following the docs by adding Cookies.set('name', 'value'); I get 'Cookies is not defined' error in the console.  This suggests that the jquery plugin is not loading but I have checked the load path again and again and it is correct. Any further ideas?

Comment: Do you see Jquery plugin in the sources under same path? Is the same loaded before you call its method?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8305703/1055987

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using the updated https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie plugin.

My working code:

```
//Brochure Modal with cookie
Cookie = Cookies.get('brochure_modal_cookie');
if (Cookie == null) {
    $("#download-brochure-button").fancybox().trigger('click');
    Cookies.set('brochure_modal_cookie', 'value', { expires: 7 });
}
```